# How to implement security in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security

Before using Rails 3 for demo purpose, I have to know how Rails 3 implements security.
Java web applications can use Spring Security framework or Apache Shiro framework.

Does Rails 3 has something similar?
Security is a high requirement for the demo, I can't ignite the demo unless I know how to implement security for Rails 3 application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be worth reading this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

For authentication there are 2 very good solutions: [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). For authorization I suggest [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/)

Comment: Yes it discusses security exploits but I need to know if Rails has security frameworks like Spring Security of Shiro. Authentication, authorization, ACL and other things.

Comment: Updated the answer with the links to gems for authentication and authorization, perhaps, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask. Are these gems are proven and trustworthy?

Comment: Devise and Authlogic are de-facto a standard for authentication in Rails. And CanCan is a creation of Ryan Bates who is famous for his Railscasts, the most comprehensive tutorials for Rails. Anyway you could ask on their github pages if you're concerned about something particular.